# Persist the dynamic values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to append the values I get from backend. For ex:

```
// Initially 

var x = '';

// on choosing first filter

x = v.state; (v.state value changes each time when filter is choosen, I want to append all the filter values choosen)



// output expected

x = firstFilter + '+' + secondFilter
```

now I need to concatenate all the filter values with "+"

Comment: no clue what the issue is...

Comment: I would like to concatenate the values, each time the value I get from BE changes

Comment: So concatenate them when it changes.... Maybe show how you see when it changes...'

Comment: @nick Why not use concatenation then? `+=` solves this issue just fine.

Comment: x += “+” + v.state ?

Comment: when I choose first filter the value need to push is "A^B" assume, when I click on second filter the value I get is "C^D".(The first value won't come anymore when you click on second) I want the output as A^B+C^D

Comment: += gives the same output two times. the v.state changes on choosing each filter, like A^B+A^B

Comment: @nick POST your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Build an array and use `join` operator to stitch the elements with " + "

```js
// Initially 

var x = [];

// on choosing first filter

x.push("A^B");

// on choosing second filter

x.push("C^D");

// output expected

console.log(x.join(" + "))

// A^B + C^D
```

Comment: here always the value is same, for first filter and the second filter.

Comment: when I choose first filter the value need to push is "A^B" assume, when I click on second filter the value I get is "C^D".(The first value won't come anymore when you click on second) I want the output as A^B+C^D

Comment: I just gave an example. Replace `FIRST FILTER` and `SECOND FILTER` with your `v.state` or what ever that is relevant to your code.

Comment: I updated the code snippet, isn't that what you wanted? I am using an array to push all the filters as they are selected, then converting it to a string.

Comment: no, 
// Initially 

var x = [];

// on choosing first filter
var n = v.state;

x.push(n); // n value changes each time


// output expected

console.log(x.join(" + "))

// A^B + C^D